# Xquery: how to filter attributes with multiple values

Tags: xml, xquery

I have the following [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IoFLs.jpg)

and I want to find players whose positions are not 'Forward'

Answer (score 0):

Here's a one-liner in XPath:

```
//player[descendant::position[not(text()="Forward")]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try a for/where/return statement:

```
for $player in //player
where fn:not($player/position = 'Forward')
return $player
```